# Slow debugging due to type names output in the output window

Tags: c#, debugging, nhibernate, visual-studio-debugging

#### For the tl;dr crowd:

1. What is causing type names to be written to the output window if it isn't Console.WriteLine or Debug.Print statements in the code? Is it the Visual Studio debugger? and
2. How can I turn it off?

#### Background and details:

I am trying to debug a program that imports CSV files into a database. Recently, I changed how I include 3rd party library dependencies. Previously, I was referencing the downloaded binary files. Now, if a 3rd party library has source code available, such as NHibernate, the project is included in my solution to be compiled along with the projects I have written myself.

Since the change, I am seeing a lot of single lines containing only a type name in the Output/Debug window that I didn't used to see before. My program is a data importer, and the main loop is causing these lines to appear 1000s of times, slowing down debugging and polluting the output window. Specifically, there are a lot of lines that say this:

```
NHibernate.Driver.NHybridDataReader
```

I have traced the code, and it seems that this is displayed whenever NHibernate is reading results back from the database. However, the line isn't output in code by the NHibernate library, so it must be coming from somewhere else. My guess is that the Visual Studio Debugger is writing it to the output window, similar to what happens during assembly binding.

I have tried compiling the NHibernate project in Release mode and everything else in Debug mode, but that didn't fix it. I also tried unchecking "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process" for just the NHibernate project, but that didn't work either.

**In summary,** my questions are:

1. What is writing type names to the output window if it isn't Console.WriteLine or Debug.Print statements in the code? and
2. How can I turn it off?

#### What my question *is not*

My question is NOT about a better way to write the data importer program so that the needed data is preloaded from the database. I know the code I have written is slow; in this particular case, in production, that is okay.  What I want is to stop polluting the debug window with tons of unneeded type information. The work loop of my program causes the types to be written 1000s of times for long CSV files, which makes the output hard to use, and slows the debugger down as it tries to sync the output window. *THIS* is what I am trying to prevent. But I'm not sure how to do that, because I'm not even sure where the messages are coming from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's difficult to make suggestions without being able to see the code, but what I would do to debug it is install the trial version of RedGate's Reflector and use it to add breakpoints to the Debug.* and Console.* functions.  If one of the breakpoints is hit, you can trace back up the call stack to find what is actually adding the lines to the output.  If none of those methods are causing the lines to be added, maybe add breakpoints to DefaultTraceListener and TextWriter.

I haven't come across anything else which can add messages to the Visual Studio output window at run time.

Comment: Interesting idea. I didn't realize RedGate's Reflector let me set breakpoints on those functions. I actually already have it installed. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: This worked! The output was coming from NHibernate after all -- but it was inside one of its log4net logger implementations; doing a Step Into wasn't hitting that code for some reason. But by setting a breakpoint in the Console.* functions, I was able to back out to what was making the call.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is irrelevant, though it solved my seemingly unrelated problem a while back (I had automated tests randomly failing and printing to console). I had to uncheck Visual Studio's "Enable property evaluation and other implicit function calls" under the Debugging menu in Options. Sorry if this is off topic/unhelpful!

EDIT: Also, have you tried changing the 'Output Window' settings in the Debugging section? You could maybe turn all debug output off and print your own debugging to a file.

Comment: No, I haven't tried that. That is an good idea -- I will try it in the morning when I am back at work. Thanks for the idea!